# add missing categoty column after applying pivot function

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, data-analysis

I have a column('Duartion_Bin') of a datframe  which contains 4 categories namely

> '<1min','1-2 min','3-5 min','>5 min'

Applying a groupby on this column

```
last3=pd.pivot_table(scada34,index=['Year','weekno'],columns=['Duration_Bin'],values=['siteid'],aggfunc='count')

Duration_Bin        1-2 min 3-5 min >5 min
weekno              
  3         2020       3        2       2
```

I want the other missing category '<1min' to appear in the columns as well...
This is an example I have several tables like this were i am facing the same issue

Comment: Does `last3.reindex(
    ['<1min','1-2 min','3-5 min','>5 min'], axis=1, fill_value=0)` answer ?

Comment: Nope mate i got the following error "TypeError: Expected tuple, got str"

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the dataset in order to reproduce it ?